# Magento 2: How can we prevent HTML from being shown in the text that comes from en_US.csv file?

Tags: magento2, frontend, localisation, html

In en-US.csv file in our custom theme, I got a translation as below.

```
"We'll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.","Within 10 minutes we'll send an email to you with your <strong>order number</strong> and complete details.<br />When your order ships we'll email tracking information to you."
```

The problem is that the HTML does also appear along with the text when the order is placed. How to process HTML but not show the HTML like  in the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no way with translation

In templates where used this translation it will be escaped

For example in default success template

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml**

```
    <?php if ($block->getOrderId()) :?>
        <?php if ($block->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
            <p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your order number is: %1.', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="order-number"><strong>%s</strong></a>', $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewOrderUrl()), $block->getOrderId())), ['a', 'strong']) ?></p>
        <?php  else :?>
            <p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.', $block->getOrderId()), ['span']) ?></p>
        <?php endif;?>
            <p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('We\'ll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.')) ?></p>
    <?php endif;?>
```

You need to overwrite this template in your custom theme or module, or change template to your own with layout.

Links:

- [Templates basic concepts](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html)
- [Extend a layout](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html)
- [Set the template used by a block](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#set_template)

Comment: But I see entries in en_US.csv like "Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.","Your Confirmation # is: <span>%1</span>." How does this work?\

Comment: In answer in fragment of phtml file you can see few examples how to work with `Phrase`. `%1` means first argument into `Phrase`. For example `__('%2 #%1', '<a href="url">ID</a>', 'Order')`, also you can allow tags with `$block->escapeHtml(__('...'), ['a']);`

Comment: Can I add something like this `<p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Within 10 minutes we\'ll send an email to you with your <strong>order number</strong> and complete details.<br />When your order ships we\'ll email tracking information to you.')) ?></p>` in success.phtml in my custom theme?

Comment: Sure. Just use `<p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Within 10 minutes we\'ll send an email to you with your <strong>%1</strong> and complete details.<br />When your order ships we\'ll email tracking information to you.', $block->getOrderId()), ['strong']) ?></p>` instead of original one

Comment: Victor, thanks. But I just want to show word "order" in bold not the actual order number.

Comment: Also, I need the line to break at When your...with <br />

Comment: The part `['strong']` means list of allowed tags, just extend it `['strong', 'br']`

Comment: Victor, thanks. But I just want to show word "order" in bold not the actual order number. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137284/discussion-between-codeforgood-and-victor-tihonchuk).

Comment: Thanks Victor. This was fixed today.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml(__("Within 10 minutes we'll send an email to you with your <strong>order number</strong> and complete details.<br />When your order ships we'll email tracking information to you."), ['strong','br']) ?>
```

Output:
[image]